# Does my visa expire along with my passport?

Tags: visas, uk, passports

I have a Philippine passport and with a visa. My passport expired on the 23rd of August. If I renew that, do I need to renew my visa as well? My visa is a settlement visa to join my parents and stay indefinitely in the UK. I saw a date on my visa the same as the expiry date of my passport. What does that mean?

Comment: Welcome to Travel.SE. It is not very clear to me what you are asking. "Settlement visa" doesn't readily turn up any informative web search results for me. What country is the visa for (UK?), and what type of visa is it? Please [edit](http://travel.stackexchange.com/posts/34507/edit) your question as best you can to follow the guidelines in the [help center](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: If your visa has an expiration date, then it expires on that date.  If it is a renewable or permanent long term visa, then likely the British Embassy has a procedure for you to have a new visa entered into your new passport.

Answer (score 8):

For the UK, you don't need to apply for a new visa if your passport expires. You can either travel with both your old passport (with the visa in it) and your new passport or [pay a fee to transfer the visa to the new passport](https://www.gov.uk/transfer-visa). But that's only true if the visa itself is still valid.

On the other hand, if the visa has an expiration date, then it's almost certainly not valid beyond that date (and it's possible the consulate chose the end of your passport's validity to set the visa's expiration date but it does not make a difference). If you still qualify for your original visa (say your family still lives in the UK), I don't think there is anything stopping you from applying for a new visa of the same type once you have a new passport but I guess you will need to go through the whole procedure again.

Note that visas allowing their holders to stay indefinitely are sometimes intended to be turned into something else after you entered the country. For example, you could [apply to settle](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk/extend-your-visa) after entering on a “family of settled person visa” or [apply for a UK residence card](https://www.gov.uk/apply-for-a-uk-residence-card/overview) after staying on an EEA family permit.